# Configuring Custom Lucene Analyzer to accept certain stop words

Tags: lucene, analyzer, stemming, hippocms

I need to modify the lucene analyzer for it to be able to recognize the word "Ben" (Dutch stop word). Kindly guide me further. How do I make Lucene Analyzer accept this word as a regular word?

Repository.xml for Server

```
<paramname="analyzer"value="org.hippoecm.repository.query.lucene.StandardHippoAnalyzer"/>
```

workspace.xml

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspacename="default">
    <!--
        virtual file system of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the FileSystem interface
    -->
    <FileSystemclass="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.mem.MemoryFileSystem">
    </FileSystem>
    <!--
        persistence manager of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the PersistenceManager interface
    -->
    <PersistenceManagerclass="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.mem.InMemPersistenceManager">
    </PersistenceManager>
    <!--
        Search index and the file system it uses.
        class: FQN of class implementing the QueryHandler interface
    -->
    <SearchIndexclass="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
      <paramname="path"value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
    </SearchIndex>
</Workspace>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple approach would be to:

Copy the following class into your local project

http://svn.onehippo.org/repos/hippo/hippo-cms7/repository/tags/hippo-repository-2.24.02/engine/src/main/java/org/hippoecm/repository/query/lucene/StandardHippoAnalyzer.java

Change the Java package and file name.

Remove the stopwords(see the above Java code) that might affect your issue.

Update your repository.xml to use the Analyser with the new package and class name

Remove you existing lucene index and restart Hippo.

```
$ mvn clean package && mvn -Pcargo.run
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks.. How do I remove the existing lucene index from the server?

Comment: Before you remove it you should stop your application container. You should have a storage directory which contains workspaces and indexes. The location of this directory can differ depending on your own configuration/setup.